# Android Studio shows failed to prepare an update: request failed with status code 404

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

Whenever I try to update Android Studio it shows an error failed to prepare an update status code 404.. I have tried almost every possible way:

- from changing no proxy to with proxy.
- from reinstalling Android Studio to redownloading Android SDK.
- from redownloading command-line-tools to changing operating system still no luck.

Even changed Android Studio version still the same error..

I did not found any similar question on web yet so I had to ask the question here. If anyone know any possible answer to solve this problem please tell me..

---

I am using Android Studio 3.6.3.

**My PC is 32bit** so I cannot download latest version. 32bit users are only receiving critical updates.

The problem started just two months before. Once I updated the Android Studio to 4.1 but now it is unable to do that.

Maybe to the site is not responding to the update request but other things are working properly like downloading SDK, NDK etc...

Comment: Well .. if 3.6.3 is the **latest for 32-bit OS** then you cannot install any newer. If the error comes from Android Studio updater .. then try disabling "checking for updates" and check for plugins updates manually... Other than that: JetBrains IDEs use `idea.log` file (`Help | Show Log in Explorer`) -- open it and check the relevant entries (exceptions) there -- e.g. what URL was requested, what subsystem did it etc.